# AttributeError: _fields_ is final (in python)

Tags: python, ctypes

While writing a python script using ctypes, I'm getting an error :AttributeError: *fields* is final

```
//demo.h
typedef struct data
{
 char * status;
}

//python script
import ctypes 
import sys
from ctypes import *

class data(Structure):pass
data._fields_ = [('Status',POINTER(c_char))]
```

So, I have hereby shown the structure in .h file and also the way I'm defining the same structure in python using ctypes.
Can anyone suggest me the solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the `_fields_` attribute of a `Structure` after it has already been assigned, if it was unset it should work. E.g. trying to do:

```
class data(Structure):
    _fields_ = []

data._fields_ = [('Status',POINTER(c_char))]
```

Would fail with `AttributeError: _fields_ is final`.

Also creating an instance of the class causes `_fields_` to be made final, so

```
    class data(Structure): pass
    d = data()
    data._fields_ = [('Status',POINTER(c_char))]
```

would also lead to the same error.

I'm assuming that something like that was attempted in the real code.

Comment: According to the docs (https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ctypes.html#structured-data-types) it should be possible, provided you do that before using the structure.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong and assigning `_fields_` after declaring a subclass of `Structure` is absolutely necessary for recursive data types.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it should work if `_fields_` was unset before. The `AttributeError: _fields_ is final` happens when trying to re-assign `_fields_`